# How do I use Emacs character classes in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, emacs

The Emacs documentation has [a section on character classes](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes). According to the manual, `[:digit:]` should match any digit character. I've tried that using `re-builder` but they never match, even though `[0-9]` matches.

How do I use character classes in an Emacs regex?

Comment: Not an emacs expert, but I believe you need to include those in a character class by itself, so `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: sidyll: that's a bit misleading; character classes can be combined with anything else within the alternative. e.g. `[a-z[:digit:]%#[:blank:]-]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. The documentation is actually explicit:

> Here is a table of the classes you can use **in a character alternative**

So `[[:digit:]]` is the right way to use character classes.

Comment: what if you need to combine two classes?